# Insert Query in vb

Tags: vb.net

Writing query in string variable but not working giving error syntax error in query expression

```
insert = "INSERT INTO [DOWNLOADS]
([Receipt_Number],[Machine_ Number],[Dates],[Time],[Shift],[Vehicle_Type],[Passage_Type],[Vehicle_Number],[Amount],[Status]) 
values 
('" & inserteddata(0) & "','" & inserteddata(1) & "','" & inserteddata(2) & "','" & inserteddata(3) & "','" & inserteddata(4) & "','" & inserteddata(5) & "','" & inserteddata(5) & "','" & inserteddata(6) & "','" & inserteddata(7) & "','" & inserteddata(8) & "','" & inserteddata(9) & "');"
```

Comment: Creating strings like this is an extremely dangerous habit to form. It provide SQL Injection attacks to a user. Try using a paramaterised query form instead.
An indication of exactly where your error is indicated to occur would be vary helpful, too.

Comment: Please read up on SQL Injection before writing any more code like this.

Comment: SQL injection aside (you should follow @Dragonthoughts' advice) your 'Machine_number' column name has a space character

Answer (score 0):

Change `[Machine_ Number]` to `[Machine_Number]`

Also as noted in comments, this is bad practice and can lead to SQL Injection

Better off using parameters instead of inline sql